# How to make this div not past through the other one on the right side?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem, I can't seem to figure out how do I make this red DIV not past through the div on the right side, I want to make it stay between the right and the left div menu.

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxp3i.jpg)

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<div class="navigationBar_default">
<div class="facetubeLogo_default"></div>

<div class="facetubeText_container_default"><center><strong class="facetubeText_default"></strong></center></div>
</div>
<div class="content_default">

<div class="leftMenu_onProfile">
<button class="leftMenu_buttonOnProfile"><img class="leftMenu_buttonImage" src="images/myProfileButton_onLeftMenu_onProfile.png" /><br>MY PROFILE</button>
<button class="leftMenu_buttonOnProfile"><img class="leftMenu_buttonImage" src="images/optionsButton_onLeftMenu_onProfile.png" /><br>GENERAL</button>
<button class="leftMenu_buttonOnProfile"><img class="leftMenu_buttonImage" src="images/generalButton_onLeftMenu_onProfile.png" /><br>OPTIONS</button>
<button class="leftMenu_buttonOnProfile"><img class="leftMenu_buttonImage" src="images/supportUsButton_onLeftMenu_onProfile.png" /><br>SUPPORT US</button>
<button class="leftMenu_buttonOnProfile"><img class="leftMenu_buttonImage" src="images/logOutButton_onLeftMenu_onProfile.png" /><br>LOG OUT</button>
</div>

<!-- there must be some stuff here, otherwise leftMenu_onProfile will glitch out. -->

<div class="contentCenter_onProfile">
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>

<!-- there must be some stuff here, otherwise leftMenu_onProfile will glitch out. -->

<div class="rightMenu_onProfile">user1<br>user2<br>user3<br>user4<br>user5</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.navigationBar_default {
    background-color:#202020;
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    margin-right:-8px;
    border:0;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
}

.facetubeLogo_default {
    background-image:url("../images/facetube_icon_30x30_png.png");
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-left:1px;
    float:left;
}

.facetubeText_container_default {
    margin-top:6px;
}

.content_default {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:32px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    margin-right:-8px;
    margin-bottom:-8px;
}

.leftMenu_onProfile {
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
}

.leftMenu_buttonOnProfile {
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    width:240px;
    height:48px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.leftMenu_buttonImage {
    float:left;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-right:-6px;
}

.contentCenter_onProfile {
  background-color:red;
  padding:2px; /* padding is originally removed */
  margin:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.rightMenu_onProfile {
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-right:-16px;
    width:300px;
    color:#ffffff;
    float:right;
}
```

I have feeling it has to do something with content_default and the width:100% but I don't know. I tried everything and I couldn't figure it out.

:/

Comment: Have you tried making .contentCenter_onProfile a span tag instead of a div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.contentCenter_onProfile {
 background-color:red;
 padding:2px; /* padding is originally removed */
 margin:0 300px;
 top:0px;
 width: 50%; /* SET THIS */
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 word-break: break-all;
 }
```

By setting the width, you can ensure the div does not overlap the right hand side div.

Setting float: left or float: right causes the elements to overlap.

Comment: That's what I was looking for a long time. Thanks a lot brother :D